# Do seasonal flights from Trondheim to Edinburgh, London, or any other part of the UK exist?

Tags: air-travel, uk, seasonal, norway

Planning a trip with my in-laws to the UK next year, and the Swedes around me keep insisting that we can fly from Trondheim instead of Arlanda, which would be a lot more convenient. I'm not finding anything on skyscanner.net though. Is it too early for the flights to show up, if they even do exist? I'm talking the June-August period. I'm mostly interested in flights to Edinburgh.

I know we can fly via Oslo, but I would prefer a non-stop option.

Comment: Ryanair flies from Skavsta to Edinburgh, London and Liverpool. Any reason not to fly from there?

Comment: Yes, Trondheim is a 1 hour drive away, Stockholm is a 6-7 hour drive away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Norwegian flies from Trondheim to London Gatwick](http://www.norwegian.com/uk/destinations/route-map/) - the route map is a pain to work with but if you choose the normal booking form, then you'll see the list of destinations they fly to from Trondheim.

Additionally, if you set SkyScanner to search for flights from Trondheim to 'United Kingdom' for month December 2011, you'll find a list of airlines that operate connecting flights (mostly via Oslo) to London airports as well as Edinburgh. For TRD to EDI, these are: SAS, Norwegian, KLM, Lufthansa.

[image: Indirect flights from Trondheim to UK]

Your mileage may vary on whether you want to a direct flight from Trondheim to London Gatwick, or rather take a connecting flight that lands at Edinburgh.

Answer (score 5):

[Norwegian](http://Www.norwegian.no) has flights from Trondheim to London Gatwick on Tuesday, Thursday and Sunday.

However, according to the [airport's webpage](https://avinor.no/en/airport/trondheim-airport/) this seems to be the only UK destination from Trondheim.